# find start and end of range given a point

Tags: ruby

I created this basic class right here:

```
class TimePeriod
  MONTHS_PER_QUARTER = 3
  QUARTER_RANGE = {
    0 => [1,3],
    1 => [4,6],
    2 => [7,9],
    3 => [10,12]
  }

  def self.quarter(month_num)
    (month_num - 1) / MONTHS_PER_QUARTER
  end

  def self.quarter_range(month_num)
    quarter = quarter month_num
    t1,t2 = QUARTER_RANGE[quarter]
    [Time.parse(Date::MONTHNAMES[t1]).beginning_of_month, Time.parse(Date::MONTHNAMES[t2]).end_of_month]
  end
end
```

It gives me a time range for a quarter, given a month provided as an integer:

```
> TimeUtils.quarter_range(Time.now.month)
 => [2015-04-01 00:00:00 -0400, 2015-06-30 23:59:59 -0400]
```

So it works. However, I have cheated. I had difficulty finding the start and end, given, let's say, the month 6. So I hardcoded the values in the QUARTER_RANGE constant. I want to be able to remove that QUARTER_RANGE constant and find the beginning and end (e.g. [4,6]) without it.

So for example, if the input 3 (March),6 (June),9(September),12(December) is passed, I will know its the end of the quarter, using modulus arithmetic:

```
3 % 3
=> 0
6 % 3
=> 0
9 % 3
=> 0
12 % 3
=> 0
```

But the tricky part is given let's say 5 (May), how can I return `[4,6]`?

Comment: Not related to the answer but while `(month_num - 1) / MONTHS_PER_QUARTER` works, what I believe you want is `(month_num / MONTHS_PER_QUARTER) - 1` which will work better in the general case. Since you are adjusting for the zero index, you should determine the index and subtract as opposed to subtracting from the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the start of the quarter like this:

```
def qtr_start(mon)
  mon - (mon - 1) % MONTHS_PER_QUARTER
end

qtr_start(9) # => 7
```

The end of the quarter is just that plus two:

```
def qtr_end(mon)
  qtr_start(mon) + 2
end

qtr_end(9) # => 9
```

Put them together:

```
def qtr_start_end(mon)
  start = mon - (mon - 1) % MONTHS_PER_QUARTER
  [ start, start + 2 ]
end

(1..12).each do |mon|
  start_end = qtr_start_end(mon)
  puts "Month #{mon} is in quarter #{start_end.inspect}"
end

# => Month 1 is in quarter [1, 3]
#    Month 2 is in quarter [1, 3]
#    Month 3 is in quarter [1, 3]
#    Month 4 is in quarter [4, 6]
#    Month 5 is in quarter [4, 6]
#    Month 6 is in quarter [4, 6]
#    Month 7 is in quarter [7, 9]
#    Month 8 is in quarter [7, 9]
#    Month 9 is in quarter [7, 9]
#    Month 10 is in quarter [10, 12]
#    Month 11 is in quarter [10, 12]
#    Month 12 is in quarter [10, 12]
```

Comment: I really like this solution right here "mon - (mon - 1) % MONTHS_PER_QUARTER".

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..12).each do |m|
  low = 3*((m-1)/3) + 1
  p m, [low, low+2]
end
```

result:

```
1
[1, 3]
2
[1, 3]
3
[1, 3]
4
[4, 6]
5
[4, 6]
6
...
```

Comment: Month 5 is not within the range of `[2,4]`. Looks like you've got an error, my friend. Anything after month 4 (July) fails.

Comment: They forgot to multiply by 3 after the integer division. I fixed it.

Comment: Good work, @Max. On my Mac, the `-` is right next to `)`. A downvote (now retracted) for an obvious typo is not right. That should prompt a comment or edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why you want it but if you want to use modulo this should work out how you want:

```
month = some_num
quarter_range = []
if month%3 == 0
  # end of quarter
  quarter_range = [month-2, month]
elsif month%3 == 1
  # beginning of quarter
  quarter_range = [month, month+2]
else
  # middle of quarter
  quarter_range = [month-1, month+1]
end

return quarter_range
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
MONTHS_PER_PERIOD = 3
PERIODS = (1..12).step(MONTHS_PER_PERIOD).map do |m|
   m..(m+MONTHS_PER_PERIOD-1)
end
  #=> [1..3, 4..6, 7..9, 10..12]

def month_to_period(m)
  PERIODS.find { |p| p.cover?(m) }
end

(1..12).each { |m| puts month_to_period(m) }
1..3
1..3
1..3
4..6
4..6
4..6
7..9
7..9
7..9
10..12
10..12
10..12
```

```
MONTHS_PER_PERIOD = 2
PERIODS = (1..12).step(MONTHS_PER_PERIOD).map do |m|
   m..(m+MONTHS_PER_PERIOD-1)
end
  #=> [1..2, 3..4, 5..6, 7..8, 9..10, 11..12] 

(1..12).each { |m| puts month_to_period(m) }
1..2
1..2
3..4
3..4
5..6
5..6
7..8
7..8
9..10
9..10
11..12
11..12
```